# Movement for Box2D Bodies

Tags: libgdx, box2d, movement, vector

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around something that should be relatively simple. I'm making a breakout clone using LibGDX and Box2D. I'm also using the Ashley ECS. For movement with bodies, I have two components - a BodyComponent (**BC**) which contains a reference to the Body that was created for the owning entity, and a PhysicsComponent (**PC**) which contains a velocity vector.

What I'm currently doing is manipulating the **PC**'s velocity vector when providing input, then setting the **BC**'s body's linear velocity to the velocity vector in the **PC**. This allows my bodies to move how I want them to move but there are two issues:

1. Bodies have no maximum velocity
2. If the pad bumps into a static body, it should bounce. However it quickly snaps back to its original position because the **PC**'s velocity is unaffected when bodies collides.

How can I manipulate bodies and make them move and interact with other bodies without the need to use another component for velocity?